# Draggable - 'text' cursor is shown while dragging in Safari

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

$(
".myCss").draggable({ cursor: 'move', other settings...)

Based on this code, draggable object should show 'move' cursor while dragging. In IE and FF it works perfectly; but in Safari, it shows 'text' cursor while dragging.

Checked in safari 4.0.5

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that did the trick for me here:
http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5678